# 'ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 4' in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, mnist

I'm building a model that takes 15000x56x56 mnist images as input and distinguish the numbers. I did the 'concatenating the images' part, and now I am trying to make the target data to work for the model. But I got a:

```
 ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 4 for 
'{{node Squeeze}} = Squeeze[T=DT_INT64, squeeze_dims=[-1]](ArgMax)' with input 
shapes: [?,4]
```

Here's the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist

X_train = x_train / 255.0
X_test = x_test / 255

# preprocessing train image
concatenated_images_train = []
for i in range(0, len(x_train), 4):
    x1 = tf.concat([x_train[i], x_train[i + 1]], axis=1)
    x2 = tf.concat([x_train[i + 2], x_train[i + 3]], axis=1)
    concatenated_image_train = tf.concat([x1, x2], axis=0)
    concatenated_images_train.append(concatenated_image_train)
x_train_concatenated = tf.stack(concatenated_images_train)

# preprocessing test image
concatenated_images_test = []
for i in range(0, len(x_test), 4):
    x1 = tf.concat([x_test[i], x_test[i + 1]], axis=1)
    x2 = tf.concat([x_test[i + 2], x_test[i + 3]], axis=1)
    concatenated_image_test = tf.concat([x1, x2], axis=0)
    concatenated_images_test.append(concatenated_image_test)
x_test_concatenated = tf.stack(concatenated_images_test)

# preprocessing train, test data
y_train = to_categorical(y_train)  
y_test = to_categorical(y_test)
y_train_concatenated = tf.concat([[y_train[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(y_train), 4)]], axis=0)
y_test_concatenated = tf.concat([[y_test[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(y_test), 4)]], axis=0)

# building model
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(56, 56)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam',
              loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train_concatenated, y_train_concatenated, epochs = 5)
```